# Не могу понять результат выполнения одной строки в коде

Tags: php

Такой скриптик:

```
1    $stri = '';
2    for ($e = 1; $e <= 3; $e++) {
3        for ($p = 0; $p < $e; $p++) {
4               $stri = $stri . $e;
5           }
6           echo $stri.'<br>';
7           $stri = '';
        }
```

Объясните пожалуйста почему при выполнении на линии 7 строки кода в результате выводится на экран:

1

22

333

Но если убрать код на линии 7, то выводится:

1

122

122333

Какое влияние имеет код на линии 7 ? Ведь перед этим, на линии 6 уже есть **echo...**

Comment: Он очищает переменную и при следующем выполнении цикла она будет в начале пустой. c тем же успехом эту строку можно было бы вставить между 2 и 3 и заодно тогда убрать 1

Comment: Да, так понятнее даже теперь. Спасибо. Вопрос решён.